# Unable to connect to test.mosquitto.org for testing

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, iot, ws

I am trying to setup a project in Angular where I need to read mqtt packets over WS. I am using ngx-mqtt package for the same.

Having set up the basic things, I tried listening to the mqtt server set up by [test.mosquitto.org](https://test.mosquitto.org/). As mentioned in the link, I am trying to listen at port 8080 over WS.

However, I keep getting the following error:

[image]

For my angular part, I am following this [tutorial](https://bugfender.com/blog/using-mqtt-on-angular-apps/) and have everything setup exactly same except for port number and server obviously, which I am using as below:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  mqtt: {
        server: 'test.mosquitto.org',
        protocol: "ws",
        port: 8080
    }
};
```

Is there a specific path or a specific topic that I should listen to. Can some one give me some more details regarding this test connection.

**Update:**

As suggested by @hardillb in the comments, I tried listening to other port and now I am not getting the attached error. I can see binary data Send/Receive in my WS section of browser's network tab.

However, as normally expected in an angular application the below subscribe call back is not triggered after the data is received.

```
private subscribeToTopic() {
      this.subscription = this.eventMqtt.topic('testing')
        .subscribe((data: IMqttMessage) => {
          let item = JSON.parse(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(data)));
          this.events.push(item);
          console.log(this.events);
      });
    }
```

Any suggestions? Do I need to approach this in any other way ? I really haven't worked before with WS, so I might be missing some basics here.

Comment: Is your app loaded via HTTPS?

Comment: @hardillb No, Currently I am just developing and testing on localhost

Comment: The error implies it's trying to connect with SSL to test.mosquitto.org (which it is not using on port 8080)

Comment: The link says: `8080 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted`. I guess this means it expects a connection without SSL, unless of course they have changed it behind the scenes.

Comment: In case you know, can you suggest me a similar public MQTT broker for testing. I have tried broker.hive.com. Unfortunately that too didn't work for me.

Comment: Just try using port 8081 and `wss` for the protocol

Comment: @hardillb: I tried that and it worked, my connection attempts are not failing now and network WS tab shows some Binary data. However, my callbacks are not invoked after getting that data. Can you suggest something please ?

Comment: That's a totally separate question