# Angular app not connecting to Mosquitto Test website (test.mosquitto.org)

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt

I'm in the same situation of this guy: [Unable to connect to test.mosquitto.org for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595363/unable-to-connect-to-test-mosquitto-org-for-testing/68995948#68995948).

I'm using angular and I'm trying to call the mqtt mosquito test [website](https://test.mosquitto.org/).
I've followed this [tutorial](https://bugfender.com/blog/using-mqtt-on-angular-apps/) and I'm getting the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://test.mosquitto.org:8080/' failed:
```

My mqtt property in the environment file is configured this way:

```
mqtt: {
    server: 'test.mosquitto.org',
    protocol: "wss",
    port: 8080,
  }
```

I'm working on localhost therefore the suggestion of changing the port to the encrypted one (8081) did not work for me. In fact, in the "network" tab of chrome dev tool, under messages, it doesn't state any SSL problem.

My mqtt service looks like this (notice I'm basically not using the endpoint, it's just empty string, maybe that is the problem):

```
export class EventMqttService {

  private endpoint: string;

  constructor(
    private _mqttService: MqttService,
  ) {
    this.endpoint = ''
  }

  topic(topic ? : string): Observable < IMqttMessage > {
    let topicName = `${this.endpoint}${topic}`;
    return this._mqttService.observe(topicName);
  }
}
```

And I'm calling this service in my component in this way:

```
notificationSubscribe() {
    console.log('STARTING dataMqtt...');
    this.notificationSubscription = this.eventMqtt.topic()
      .subscribe(
        (dataMqtt: IMqttMessage) => {
          console.log('dataMqtt: ', dataMqtt);
        }
      )
  }
```

I see in chrome dev tool that my app keeps calling (so I guess it is half-working), but it gets the same error over and over.

EDIT 1: I changed to protocol "ws" with port 8080, as suggested, but I get the same error.

EDIT 2: adding `path:'/mqtt'` to the mqtt object does not solve the issue; it gives the following error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt' failed:`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to force a secure WebSocket connection to the unsecured port.

From the test.mosquitto.org website:

> - 8887 : MQTT, encrypted, server certificate deliberately expired
> - 8080 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, unauthenticated
> - 8081 : MQTT over WebSockets, encrypted, unauthenticated
> - 8090 : MQTT over WebSockets, unencrypted, authenticated

As you can see port 8080 is for an unencrypted connection yet you have set the protocol to `wss`. `wss` stands for "Web Sockets Secured" where as `ws` stands for "Web Sockets"

You have 2 choices, either swap port to 8081 or change the protocol to `ws` not `wss`

Comment: ok, I changed to "ws", but I still get the same error:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/' failed:

Comment: Try adding `path: '/mqtt'` to the `mqtt` object (after the port number)

Comment: Similar problem; it gives to following error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt' failed: